# Oracle - How to change field value based on certain value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a concatenated full name field:

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(u3.LAST_NAME, ', '), u3.FIRST_NAME), NVL(u3.MIDDLE_NAME, '')) AS TEAMLEAD_NAME
```

If the 3 name fields are null, I want the record to show nothing, ie. `''`.

But when all 3 fields are null, the record is showing a `,` (coming from the `last_name` part).

I tried placing a `NVL(x, '')` around the entire field, around all 3 separate name fields, etc., but I'm still getting a `,` returned.

What is the best way to write this so that I get a blank field returned if all 3 name fields are null?

Thanks

Comment: Your statement is confusing.  In Oracle, `''` *is* treated as `NULL`.  So, `NVL(u3.MIDDLE_NAME, '')` is a no-op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it quickly, though the conditions could be improved:

```
CASE
    WHEN u3.LAST_NAME IS NULL AND u3.FIRST_NAME IS NULL AND u3.MIDDLE_NAME IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(u3.LAST_NAME, ', '), u3.FIRST_NAME), NVL(u3.MIDDLE_NAME, '')) 
END "TEAMLEAD_NAME"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
NULLIF(u3.LAST_NAME || ', ' || u3.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || u3.MIDDLE_NAME, ',  ') AS TEAMLEAD_NAME
```

This turns the value back to `NULL` if all three names are missing.  I added a space between the first and middle names.

Comment: It doesn't. It still returns a comma as the string you're comparing in the NVL will never be null because you're concatenating a comma regardless if the names are null or not.

Comment: @doodlebob . . . With `NULLIF()` it should do what I intended.

Comment: @doodlebob - there was a minor syntax error which I've taken the liberty of correcting. Once that was done the code works properly. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=192ff4e614d5a6b26ecb4b32faac6d91)